# Unable to handle move gesture in arkit with USDZ formate models

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, arkit, scnnode

I am loading usdz models in arkit (not QLPreviewController) , then i have added gestures to rotate , move and scale in realworld its working fine for .obj models but not working properly for usdz models.

I have tried with `SCNTransaction` its not working,

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.viewController.sceneView];
                SCNVector3 pPoint = [self.viewController.sceneView projectPoint:self.movedObject.position];
                CGPoint previousPosition = CGPointMake(pPoint.x, pPoint.y);
                NSLog(@"%f \n %f",pPoint.y,translation.y);
                CGPoint currentPosition = CGPointMake(previousPosition.x + translation.x , previousPosition.y + translation.y);
                ARHitTestResult * hitResults = [self.FSVC smartHitTest:currentPosition];
                simd_float3 translation1 = [self.FSVC getTrans:hitResults];
                self.movedObject.simdPosition = translation1;
                NSLog(@"%f",translation.y);
                [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.viewController.sceneView];
```

I want add gestures for any type of models in `arkit` with high accuracy.

Thanks in advance.